# linking failed with undefined reference to libboost_thread

Tags: c++, boost, compiler-errors, linker

I am compiling an opensource project to run on my machine which is [this project](http://ahclab.naist.jp/pseudogen/). It requires boost library so I installed the Boost_1_55 library on my ubuntu machine but the compiling process was not successfully finished by printing out some error messages as follows.

```
libtool: link: g++ -g -O3 -Wall -DKENLM_MAX_ORDER=6 -W -Wall -Wno-sign-compare -I./.. -pthread -I/usr/include -g -O2 -o .libs/query query_main.o  ./.libs/libklm.so ../util/.libs/libklm_util.so -lz -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lboost_program_options -lboost_thread -lboost_system -lpthread -lrt -pthread
../util/.libs/libklm_util.so: undefined reference to `boost::thread::join()'
../util/.libs/libklm_util.so: undefined reference to `boost::thread::~thread()'
./.libs/libklm.so: undefined reference to `boost::thread::start_thread()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15712690/6577494) seems the solution for my problem but the result of `ls -al /usr/local/lib | grep thread` showed me like below.

```
libboost_thread.a
libboost_thread.so -> libboost_thread.so.1.55.0
libboost_thread.so.1.49.0
libboost_thread.so.1.55.0
```

I don't know what else to check more. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: These functions are all inline and defined in boost headers. You seem to have several versions of boost libraries on your system. Do you also have header versions corresponding to these libraries?

Comment: @n.m. Can you tell me how to check whether I have the proper header versions corresponding to the library? Actually, I don't exactly understand your point. Should header version match the library?

Comment: #include "boost/version.hpp" and print BOOST_VERSION.

Comment: @n.m. I found out that current version of boost is 1_49 instead of 1_55 so your assumption was right. Then, how do I change the header version from 1.44 to 1.55?

Comment: I followed these instructions [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6639881/3003942) and I used "BOOST_LIB_VERSION" to print the header version.

Comment: @n.m. headers for boost lib are included from /usr/local/include, but the problem is these files belong to 1.49 which is old version. Thus, I deleted it so, there is no errors anymore! Thank you for your help. I really appreciate your comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add `/usr/local/lib` to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` like this

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Comment: Thank you for giving me an answer. 
Unfortunately, It didn't work..
 `$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH<br/>
 $ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH<br/>
 /usr/local/lib:`<br/>
 $make`<br/>
but it emits the same error messages.

Answer (score 0):

You have the static Boost library object (libboost_thread.so) but do you have the Boost development files installed? Check to see if the /usr/include/boost/thread directory exists and has *.hpp files in it. If not you may need to install the libboost-thread-dev package for your distribution or download the header files directly from Boost.org.

Comment: Thanks, I think it is installed also since there are more than 50 files in the /usr/include/boost/thread directory.